# Can we create an XMPP chat client code in windows just like in android?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, windows-xp, xmpp

I need my android phone and my PC (win-xp-sp3) to be able to communicate with each other.

I am successfully running a xmpp code in my android phone through SL4a/python and it can send and receive communication.Now the communication my phone is sending i want to receive on my pc through a code.(which at present i am receiving thorough my gtalk client)

My questions are: how do i go about it?, is there any pre existing code,script,link that i can refer to? or can i hijack anyway the msgs received by gtalk in my pc?

I tried to use the same android code to listen for the chat from PC by removing the android part of the code, but I was getting error on xmpp module not existing. so i copied the xmpp.py file from google developers website to my lib folder. but now if i try to run it i am getting error "No module named google.appengine.api".

So i did some homework and downloaded gdata-2.0.17.zip from google developers website.

My questions are: am I on the right path? what should i do next? Is there any document/link regrading the same that you know?

I know the question was long but i tried to be specific to what I am looking for.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine is Google's cloud computing service. If you're not creating a web application using that, you need to find an XMPP module for Python which doesn't depend on Google App Engine.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081634/which-is-the-most-mature-python-xmpp-library-for-a-gchat-client seems like it's relevant to this question.

Comment: I am looking into it .. seems like sleekxmpp might solve my problem. I'll update as soon as i get a positive response out if it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of [XMPP client libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) available that will work on Windows in pretty much any language you want to use.  Pick one and simply write an app that connects to the gtalk server.  You don't need anything google specific to do that.